# React app working well locally but fails after deployment on Heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, web-deployment, production-environment, heroku-cli

I'm deploying my react website on Heroku. It's running fine locally and on running the command 'heroku local web'. The website is getting deployed successfully but getting Application Error.

```
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
heroku logs --tail
```

On running heroku logs -tail , my log file looks something like this:

```
2020-04-20T09:47:52.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-04-20T09:47:55.522526+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at https://{some-ip-address}
2020-04-20T09:47:55.523069+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /{filename path}
2020-04-20T09:47:55.523174+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
2020-04-20T09:47:55.523277+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /{filename path}
2020-04-20T09:47:55.523531+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting the development server...
2020-04-20T09:47:55.523534+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-20T09:47:55.631808+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-04-20T09:48:17.332436+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host={hostname}.herokuapp.com request_id={some_request_id} fwd={ip address} dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

What could be causing possible reason of failure? How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to run a development server on Heroku as indicated by:

```
Starting the development server...
```

What is your `npm start` task? Do you have a `npm run build` script? I would bet your start script starts webpack in watch mode?

Instead, try something like this for your `package.json`:

```js
{
  //...
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "dev": "webpack --mode development --watch",
    "start": "node server.js"
  }
}
```

This assumes you're using a node server, you will need to replace the `start` command with whatever server you're using or use the [Heroku static buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static).

If Heroku sees a `build` script, it will run this when deploying your app.

#### Option 2

Make sure you have a `Procfile` set if you server is not being started with "npm start":

```
web: npm run server
```

Comment: My package.json file looks like this:
`"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "build-package": "npm run build-package-css && babel src --out-dir dist"
  }`

Comment: What kind of Heroku app is this? Is it static? Node? Something else?

Comment: Ok, how are you serving the app? What is the script name? Maybe create a Procfile? I updated answer with Procfile

Comment: I'm getting this error after running npm start

`Error: Cannot find module ‘{fileName}/server.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:864:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! {fileName}@1.8.0 start: `node server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1`

Comment: Does "server.js" exist? I put that as an example. How are you running your server locally? Do you have a server like express or something? Are you sure this isn't just a static application? I need more info to be helpful.

Comment: @DanaWoodman - "start": "react-scripts start" it starts [WebPackDevServer](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/) internally, all these scripts are bound within react-scrips . I am facing the same issue, hence I am trying to identify if this could help in a way.

Comment: Have a look at the Create React App build pack if you don't have/need a server: https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/mars/create-react-app-buildpack

Comment: You need some sort of server to run a backend to serve your CRA app when someone requests your domain. You could also create a simple Node (or really any server to serve the /build directory but the above build pack should work. Another option is to use Netlify or Vercel Now for easier static site hosting.

Comment: Also here's another URL that may be helpful https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/